# Automatic JS Slider?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on making a js slider to be both automated and have the arrow controls, I have the arrow controls but I'm unable to make it so that it's automated too.

Here is the code;

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<style>
.mySlides {display:none}
.w3-left, .w3-right, .w3-badge {cursor:pointer}
.w3-badge {height:13px;width:13px;padding:0}
</style>


<div class="w3-content w3-display-container" style="max-width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://www.rugby-heaven.co.uk/media/wysiwyg/Free_Printing_Lions_Front.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://www.rugby-heaven.co.uk/media/wysiwyg/All_Blacks_Training.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://www.rugby-heaven.co.uk/media/wysiwyg/TourJersey_1.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="w3-center w3-container w3-section w3-large w3-text-white w3-display-bottommiddle" style="width:100%">
    <div class="w3-left w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</div>
    <div class="w3-right w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</div>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(1)"></span>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(2)"></span>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(3)"></span>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
     dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-white", "");
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " w3-white";
}
</script>
```

Could someone please shine a light on getting it to run automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it to run automatically by calling `setInterval` function.

> The setInterval() method calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified intervals (in milliseconds).
>
> The setInterval() method will continue calling the function until
>   clearInterval() is called, or the window is closed.

I have created a function here so you can create an idea how to make it. 
You can read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) for `setInterval()`

I didn't run this code so let me know if it has any errors.

```
function makeInfinite(time){
    setInterval(function(){
       plusDivs(1);
    },time*1000);
}

makeInfinite(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

setInterval() is what you are looking for. You probably will also want to try to add in a way to delay the interval whenever someone clicks on a different slide, since it would be a bad user experience to click "slide3" only to have it leave half a second later because of the automation.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<style>
.mySlides {display:none}
.w3-left, .w3-right, .w3-badge {cursor:pointer}
.w3-badge {height:13px;width:13px;padding:0}
</style>


<div class="w3-content w3-display-container" style="max-width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://www.rugby-heaven.co.uk/media/wysiwyg/Free_Printing_Lions_Front.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://www.rugby-heaven.co.uk/media/wysiwyg/All_Blacks_Training.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://www.rugby-heaven.co.uk/media/wysiwyg/TourJersey_1.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="w3-center w3-container w3-section w3-large w3-text-white w3-display-bottommiddle" style="width:100%">
    <div class="w3-left w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</div>
    <div class="w3-right w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</div>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(1)"></span>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(2)"></span>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(3)"></span>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
     dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-white", "");
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " w3-white";
}

setInterval(function(){showDivs(++slideIndex);},3000);
</script>
```